# Cómo validar antes de actualizar campos en una tabla MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de logs y tengo varios problemas. Lo podré explicar mejor viendo este trozo de código:

```
foreach ($EANsNoCoinciden as $key => $value) {
   
    $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_nuevos_definitiva (`ean`) VALUES ('$value[0]')";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    var_dump($resultado);
    if($resultado){
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value[0]." "."fue insertado correctamente. <br>";

            $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `insercion_articulos_nuevos_definitiva`='Correcto' WHERE `id`=$idfinal";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
        }else{
            echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".$value[0]." "."tuvo errores en la inserción en su correspondiente tabla. Se aconseja que se revise. El error tuvo que ver con Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService); 

            $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `insercion_articulos_nuevos_definitiva`='Ha habido errores al insertar los artículos nuevos en la tabla articulos_nuevos_definitiva' WHERE `id`=$idfinal";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
        }

        
}
```

Veamos, con este código inserto `ean` que es una PK con un formato de 13 dígitos, en la tabla `articulos_nuevos_definitiva`. Lo hago con PHP, SQL y SGBD MySQL. Los problemas que tengo son los siguientes:

-Pongamos que inserto 10 ean. Son 10 inserciones que se hacen hasta que acabe el bucle. ¿Qué ocurre si uno de ellos falla? Porque claro, he de actualizar a correcto o poner el mensaje de error (o el MySQLi_error) en el campo de la tabla de logs correspondiente. Básicamente porque creo que en cuanto falla uno ya pone que hay error, y no necesariamente, ya que puede ser que no se haya insertado porque el ean está repetido, por ejemplo.

-Por otro lado, hay otras sentencias SQL, dónde se puede tener que recoger datos de otra tabla para insertarlos en un campo de esta tabla del ejemplo, y quizás para unos artículos ese campo tiene valor y en otros casos lo tiene vacío o null.

El tema es el siguiente: se supone que tengo que controlar absolutamente todo lo que puede ocurrir para que no dé error, y si hay error que sea verdaderamente un error (y no simplemente que el dato está vacío, o que el `ean` esté repetido, y cosas así). ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo (usando como ejemplo este código)? Estoy muy perdido al respecto, porque además hay que intentar que el sistema de logs no sobrecargue excesivamente el tiempo de carga de ejecución del programa. Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Creo que lo que estás buscando lo podrías solucionar usando *transacciones*. Échale un vistazo.

Comment: Me pregunto por qué no usas un TRIGGER AFTER INSERT y ya está ¿? Dentro del TRIGGER programas la lógica que quieras, controlas lo que haya que controlar y actualizas lo que haya que actualizar. Así, cada vez que se inserte algo en la tabla el TRIGGER se dispara solo y te mantiene las cosas al día. Los SGBD son más que un almacén de datos y con tu código PHP solo estás intentando reinventar la rueda.

Comment: ¿Se puede realizar con transacciones y sería lo correcto? Sí. Pero no me dejan utilizarlas xD Lo tengo que realizar con SQL a pelo.